# How to take pdf of LinkedIn profile?

Tags: pdf, linkedin-api

Iam trying to take pdf of my profile from LinkedIn. My aim is to create a resume from my LinkedIn profile. But unfortunately they changed the UI of LinkedIn and now save as pdf option is not available. If any alternative way is available for this purpose please help. I found some options but all of them require sharing of my LinkedIn url with it. I dont want to share my LinkedIn account with other tools. I dont want to just save linkedin html page as a pdf. I want to take print of linkedin profile as a resume.

Answer (score 2):

Try printing the page to pdf ?

Comment: No actually what I want to get is print my profile as a resume.. Not like just print html page as pdf..

Comment: Why don't you try this : https://aarontgrogg.com/blog/2013/07/21/how-to-print-a-linkedin-profile-as-a-resume/

Comment: ^ it creates a bookmarklet, and the code seems to be safe enough. Just paste the code on your URL

Comment: Additionally, this is the LinkedIn official page for printing a profile : https://www.linkedin.com/help/linkedin/answer/4281/printing-a-profile-and-recommendations?lang=en

Comment: I dont feel safe to use another tool for printing my personal page.. Then LinkedIn official page for printing a profile is not working for me. I already tried it. I dont have save to pdf option in more. It only have share profile option.

Comment: It's a bookmarklet, there's also a public GitHub repo which has a decent pulls...The code looked safe to me.

Answer (score 1):

[Follow the image below to export PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/M5Wc4.jpg)

But linkedin allows exporting only summary, experience, education sections.

If you are a person who has lot of accomplishments, projects etc those will be not be exported using this format.

You can use chrome extensions such as **[ResponsiveCV](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/responsive-cv-resume-make/cnnffgdlkepdhppahlfeojbpjlbbpgep)** to export complete linkedin profile including accomplishments.